# Installation 15.04 can't start

Tags: boot, system-installation, 15.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 15.04 (x64) on my new laptop, but running in to a problem everytime I try to boot from the Flashdrive.

I can boot in to the flash drive, can choose

- Try ubuntu before installing
- Install Ubuntu
- OEM Install
- ... (Don't remember this one)

But, when I try option no 1 or 2 I got this message on my screen

[ful of numbers] nouveau E[   PFIF0][0000:01:00.0] SCHED_ERROR [UNK08]

I'm using Windows 10 as the main OS on the computer, it's a Intel chipset with nvidia gpu..

Anyone know how to get pass the error?! =)

(I know, my english are not sooooo good!)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like an issue with the nouveau (kernal video) drivers.  Try booking up with the "nomodeset" option.

press the shift key when the bios screen clears
Select grub menu;
Press **e** to edit;
arrow down to the kernel boot line where it says "quiet splash";
type "**nomodeset**" -without the quotes- at the end of this line;
Press ctl-x to save and boot.

Once into the desktop, choose Additional Drivers and install the recommended Nvidia driver, though you won't be able to use it until you've installed Linux and restarted.

Comment: Just want to mention that this answer definitely helped me. Thanks a ton

Also, be careful when editing the boot commands (when trying to insert "nomodeset")- it was laggy at least for me and I accidentally changed some other line without noticing (and thus it failed to boot the first time). Had to be much more careful after.